# error CS1704: DLL loaded twice ? -razormachine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, razor

I want to use RazorMachine on my VS2012 MVC 4 .NET webapp, called "Haas2013".

Everything is working, until I hit a line where I actually call RazorMachine.

I keep getting this error:

```
error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 'haas2013, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. 
Try removing one of the 
references or sign them to enable side-by-side.

               Line 25:  RazorMachine rm = new RazorMachine();
-->Error here: Line 26:  ITemplate template = rm.ExecuteContent(res.Body);
```

When looking into Debug/Windows/Symbols, I can see the DLL of my project "haas2013.dll" loaded twice.

```
haas2013.dll    C:\Users\Reinhard\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6224be98\f18ecea8\assembly\dl3\43249f4b\692c79c0_cd2ace01\haas2013.dll    No  Yes Symbols loaded. C:\Users\Reinhard\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6224be98\f18ecea8\assembly\dl3\43249f4b\692c79c0_cd2ace01\haas2013.pdb    29  1.0.0.0 27.03.2013 10:30    05740000-057A0000   [3820] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)     
haas2013.dll    E:\Arbeiten\haas2013\haas2013\haas2013\obj\Debug\haas2013.dll   No  Yes Symbols loaded. E:\Arbeiten\haas2013\haas2013\haas2013\obj\Debug\haas2013.pdb   84  1.0.0.0 27.03.2013 10:30    08F90000-08FF0000   [3820] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)
```

Is this the source of the error, or is this the expected behaviour?

I am using IIS-Express.

Comment: Turned out, that Glimpse was the problem. After uninstall-package this went away... too bad, no more Glimpse..